# Custom Post Type order by modified date and custom meta field issue

Tags: custom-post-types, query, order

I'm creating a plugin with some kind of offers that users can publish. User, in his custom administration panel, can managed his own offers. Offers are free and premium. If offer is premium it take place above the free offers in whole list. User can refresh premium offers daily so offer that has been refresh is landing at the top of the list.

I figured it out like this:
offers has `custom fields "premium"` and if offer is "premium" the value is "2", otherwise (free offer) the value is "1".

When user is refreshing his premium offer, it's `'post_modified'` is changed.

What kind of query do I have to made to make this happen:
newest (with latest modified date) premium offers (with custom meta "premium" equal "2") on top of the list and other offers below it.

My actual query looks like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'mycustomposttype',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_key' => 'premium',
    'orderby' => 'modified meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
        'key' => 'paid',
        'value' => array('paid','free'),
        'compare' => 'IN'
        )
    ),
);
```

but the newest offer is in the end of list. even when i changed order to 'DESC'.
Any help (or new way to do this) will be much appreciate.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me: "When user is refreshing his premium offer, it's 'post_modified' is changed." What does that mean exactly in context? How are your offers implemented? And, for the record, I am betting that the problem isn't your query, it is your data structure.

Comment: when you fires `wp_update_post` the `post_modified` is changed to actual time. so when user click on 'refresh' link i make update post hook. Users add new offers with form in their account. What do you mean that my data structure is failure?

Comment: It is very difficult to tell what you are doing but it it sounds like the way that you have chosen to organize your data makes the query you want difficult.

Comment: so maybe you can help me with reorganize structure for this kind of problem. very important is separation of posts to "free" and "premium" so that premium posts must be shown before the rest, non premium. refreshing is also very important. any clue? it's very important for me to figured out asap.

Comment: any solution to make this happen? order posts by type (premium or free) and let user modified the date of his posts. than the latest modified posts with premium type is on top of the list. Please help!

Comment: Unless I understand _exactly_ what you are doing and what you need to do, I can't help. And as I said, it is very difficult to tell what you are doing.

Comment: @s_ha_dum the point is:
user can create post in custom post type. In the form that user creates new post is field: premium or free.

In archive page those custom post type that user creates must sort like this: first premium post, then rest. of course order by date so the latest premium first, than "latest" rest ie:

`premium post - 13.04.2014
premium post - 1.04.2014
standard post - 13.04.2014
standard post - 5.04.2014
and so on...`

in control panel user must have some option to bump up their post so post from 30 days ago can jump to the top of archive page again.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, I believe that the following will do what you need:

```
function orderby_mod_wpse_140999($orderby) {
  remove_action('posts_orderby','orderby_mod_wpse_140999');
  global $wpdb;
  return $orderby.", {$wpdb->posts}.post_modified DESC";
}
add_filter('posts_orderby','orderby_mod_wpse_140999');

$args = array(
  'meta_key' => 'premium',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value',
  'order' => 'ASC'
);
$q = new WP_Query($args);
var_dump($q->request);
```

The key names may be wrong and it may be (probably is) better rewritten as a `pre_get_posts` action, something like:

```
function orderby_mod_wpse_140999($orderby) {
  remove_action('posts_orderby','orderby_mod_wpse_140999');
  global $wpdb;
  return $orderby.", {$wpdb->posts}.post_modified DESC";
}
add_filter('posts_orderby','orderby_mod_wpse_140999');

function pgp_orderby_mod_wpse_140999($qry) {
  if ($qry->is_main_query() && is_archive()) {
    $qry->set('meta_key','premium');
    $qry->set('orderby','meta_value');
    $qry->set('order','ASC');
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','pgp_orderby_mod_wpse_140999');
```

Again, I am guessing a bit. For the `pre_get_posts` solution the code would need to go somewhere that will allow the hook to apply to the main query.